# Setear hora en local

Tags: date, datepicker

necesito mostrar la fecha y hora en mi app, pero me trae la hora `+3`, soy de Argentina y necesitaría configurar la hora local de Buenos Aires.

Dejo mi código:

```
Date hoy = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
//armamos la fecha con el formato DD.MM.AAAA
String shoy = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(hoy).toString();
fechainf.setText(shoy);
String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(hoy);
```

En `fDate` obtengo `YYYY-MM-AA` correctamente pero la hora `HH = HH + 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para configurar la zona horaria debes usar `DateFormat.setTimeZone()` para imprimir la fecha en la zona horaria que necesites.

En tu caso intenta con `DateFormat.setTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires")`

Comment: Muchas gracias!! funcionó con tu recomendación:

SimpleDateFormat fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); fDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"));